# patterns for bash functions: best approaches

Tags: bash, function, return

One approach to returning values in a bash function uses command substitution:

```
function foo () {
    echo ${1}-foo
}

function bar () {
    echo ${1}-bar
}
```

This approach facilitates transparent assignment syntax:

```
reply_bar=$(bar koo)
echo $(foo reply_bar)            # koo-bar-foo
```

and evaluating function arguments in place:

```
echo $(foo $(bar koo))           # koo-bar-foo
```

Another approach is to pass in the name of a variable that you want some output to be assigned.

```
function foo () {
    eval "$1"="'${2}'-foo"
}

function bar () {
    eval "$1"="'${2}'-bar"
}

bar reply_bar koo
foo reply_foo "$reply_bar"
echo $reply_foo                  # koo-bar-foo
```

But now you cannot pass into a function the output of another evaluated function, like `$(foo $(bar koo))` did. Instead you have to do something ugly like:

```
foo reply_foo $(bar reply_bar koo; echo $reply_bar)
echo $reply_foo                  # koo-bar-foo
```

or wrap it in a `compose` function that does something similar.

So, here's my question: how can I write my functions so that they are composable, assign output to variables, and are not as ugly as sin?

Comment: Status codes are not lost when you use command substitution, for the record. You just have to capture them immediately after each assignment.  In the nested case, I'm not sure where you would expect the innermost status code to wind up.

Comment: And FWIW, my answer to your question is, "if those are your requirements, don't use bash".

Comment: I don't understand what the end goal is here?

Comment: BTW, your original code is missing some quotes it really needs to have to be fully correct. (And the use of `eval` is unfortunate in and of itself -- as in, since the `$2` is double-expanded in both cases, one could pull off shell injection through any use of either of the original `foo` or `bar` functions).

Comment: You are correct about not losing status code in command substitution. I've amended my question accordingly.

I don't have requirements. I'm trying to learn.

Comment: To see what I was saying about the use of `eval` being dangerous, try running `foo out '$(touch /tmp/i-am-insecure)'` -- and be glad that `touch` wasn't a `rm`.

Comment: That said, I wouldn't call any of what you're doing above function composition. You aren't passing functions themselves to shell functions; you're passing the *output* of *invoking* functions to other functions.

Comment: I *have* actually built a real framework for functional composition in shell in the past, by the way -- it was heavily inspired by [execline](https://skarnet.org/software/execline/), and I'd suggest you make the effort to grok same if this is genuinely an area of interest. (My own effort there is property of my employer of the time, and thus not publicly available).

Comment: I hadn't considered its vulnerability to an injection. The pattern I described using eval is recommended in a number of places here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Those places are dangerously wrong, if their quoting is genuinely akin to that given above. If you have links handy, I'd appreciate them.

Comment: BTW, see [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) for a treatise on safe practices for indirect expansion and assignment, *including* discussion of the practices necessary to use `eval` safely. And [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048), discussing *unsafe* uses of `eval`.

Comment: I've modified code in response to your comments.

My comment was specifically about using eval in this context, not to my careless quoting. Of course, using eval means that extra caution is warranted...

Comment: @JacobLee, to be clear about what I meant by "careless quoting" -- `eval "$foo=$bar"` is much less safe than `eval "$foo=\$bar"` (as the former trusts the destination variable name to be safe, but the latter trusts the *value* to be safe as well). `eval "$foo="'$bar'` would be an equivalent to the (safer) former -- the point is that when using `eval` safely, quoting must be formulated such as to avoid double-expansion of untrusted content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the capture into its own function, of course!

```
# Underscore-prefixing variables to avoid restricting the namespace we can assign to
capturing_output_into() {

  local _destvar _output _retval        # separate local declaration to avoid impacting
                                        # exit status later (want to return exit status of
                                        # "$@", not of "local").

  _destvar=$1; shift                    # capture destination variable name

  _output="$( "$@" )"; _retval=$?       # capture output and retval; on the same line so
                                        # future logging or extensions aren't likely to
                                        # interrupt retval by mistake.

  printf -v "$_destvar" %s "$_output"   # store output in destination
  return "$_retval"                     # and return captured retval
}

foo() { echo "${1}-foo"; }
bar() { echo "${1}-bar"; }

capturing_output_into reply_foo foo "$(bar koo)"
```

---

That said, there's no composition of `foo` and `bar` going on here -- we're passing (the name of / a reference to) `foo` as an argument to `capturing_output_into`, but that's all there is. If you wanted *real* function composition you'd perhaps be implementing something like `partial`, but *that* really does tend to involve `eval` (and thus be a case where (1) great care and caution is needed to build an actually correct implementation; and (2) a language built with appropriate primitives is a better choice).

Might you consider [scsh](https://scsh.net/)? :)

Comment: You are correct, of course. I did not mean composition of functions, as in : h = f o g. I was not precise.